# How to return 'object', not string or html using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

because my server host disabled the use of

```
file_get_contents()
```

inside simple_html_dom.php,

I replaced

```
file_get_html()
```

with

```
function file_get_html_using_CuRL($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

But the code below

```
 $html = file_get_html_using_CuRL($url);
 $arvl2_arr = $html->find('div[class="arvl2"]');
```

returns error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
```

I am guessing that the problem is because $html isn't object?

The code worked when i used

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `str_get_html()` function available in SimpleHTMLDOM that you can use in order to load up the `curl` return values.

Just modofy it accordingly:

```
function file_get_html_using_CuRL($url) {

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = str_get_html($output);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

This returns a SimpleHTMLDOM object in which you can now chain up methods of your liking like `->find()`, etc. then make your necessary logic.

Note: Of course load up the SimpleHTMLDOM library first.

Comment: $output = str_get_html($output); was the key. thanks alot

Comment: @Joon.P sure glad this helped